# Implementing Egyptian Algorithm in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, multiplication

I want to find a multiplication of two numbers in Java recursively with using only Addition, Subtraction and Comparison. So, I googled and I found `Egyptian Algorithm` that meets the question requirement.

However, I'm not sure how to find the multiplication result after we reach the `base case`.

Example:

```
13 x  30

1  -- 30

2  -- 60

4  -- 120

8  -- 240 //we stop here because the double of 8 is larger than 13
```

To find the result we add the numbers from the `left column` that equals 13 which they are `1+4+8` and on the other hand we add its opposite numbers from the `right column` which they are `30+120+240 = 390` which is the result.

But now how to do last part programatically ? how to check which numbers to add? I hope you guys get my point. Hints only needed.

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself? Do you have any code snippets?

Comment: I'm actually asking about the last part of the problem. Not how to code the whole algorithm. I will post my code in a min.

Comment: ok - what have you tried for the last part of the problem?

Comment: tell us what u tried and how the answer solved your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did it using Brute Force Algorithm. It's a BigO-(n) though. I'm sure there is more efficient way to implement it. For now. I'm settling with this.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here's pseudocode to solve the problem:

```
function egyptian(left, right)
  prod := 0
  while (left > 0)
    if (left is odd)
      prod := prod + right
    left := halve(left)
    right := double(right)
  return prod
```

Basically, instead of waiting until the end, it is easier to check each row of the template as it is created and sum if it belongs in the output. I discuss this algorithm at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/01/15/three-binary-algorithms/).

Comment: Could you also give the pseudocode for the halve function? I'm having trouble figuring out how that can be done using only the available operations.

Comment: Also, additionally, `is odd` is also problematic using the given operations.

Comment: The ancient Egyptians used pairs of pebbles. You can do the same. To halve a number, take one and throw one away, take one and throw one away, take one and throw one away, and so on until none are left; the pebbles you kept are half the original number. Finding if a number is odd is similar: take one and throw one away, repeatedly, until either none or one pebble is left, which tells you if the number is even or odd.

Comment: Good point, I didn't realize those options, and they do indeed make it possible. It doesn't make the algorithm particularly attractive because it becomes `O(log(n)^2)`, while the algorithm the OP is currently working on is `O(log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

Do a loop through the created results *in reverse order*

Each time, if your multiplicant remainder (which starts equal to your multiplicant) is larger than the number in the left column, subtract the left column from your multiplicant and add the right column to your result (which starts at zero).

Answer (score 0):

You might have found this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication).

Have a look at the last part of the section called "decomposition". You'll find the sub-algorithm you have to implement.

Comment: The only way I can think of to implement the decomposition is by `for loops` . But I think it will be very slow and costs too much. multiple of `for loops` and recursive calls .  And I still don't know how it would help me finding the `powers` to find the last result. I will continue tomorrow.